# Destroying bean of a given package and create again before each cucumber scenario (test) to prevent state from leaking between scenarios

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am trying to destroy the beans before each test. So that when a test start running it should create fresh beans to execute the test as required classes are Autowired.

I am using destroyBean method of ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.

```java
@Autowired
private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

val beanClass = Class.forName(beanDefinition.getBeanClassName());
val beans = beanFactory.getBeansOfType(beanClass);
beanFactory.destroyBean(bean);
```

I am expecting the constructor to be called before each test as I am destroying all the beans.
But it is not calling the constructor and using the old beans.

Comment: please add the full test code , because we cant see if you have placed this piece in the right place ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Scope("cucumber-glue")
```

Placing the above annotation on top of each bean fixed the problem. Sample -

```
@Component
@Scope("cucumber-glue")
public class TestComponent {

}
```